# Want to update to windows 10 but have moved the users directory

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I was about to update my PC to windows 10 today until I ran into a problem. A while ago I decided to follow [this](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7) guide to move the users directory from my SSD with minimal space, to my hard drive with more space. Now when I try to update to Windows 10 without losing any of my files I get this error: `You can't keep windows settings, personal files, and apps because your current version of windows might be installed in an unsupported directory`.

[image: You can't keep windows settings, personal files, and apps because your current version of windows might be installed in an unsupported directory]

I really need some help here and I am hoping someone here can provide me with a solution to this without me having to lose my files. :)

Comment: Before ANY upgrade, do backup all your important files.Error message or not. And with tested backups, simply go for: 1) keep nothing (install win10 so you get a key). 2) Do a nice clean win10 install with the new key. 3) Restore your personal files/change user folder again.

Comment: @Hennes I have never done a proper Windows backup before, only system restore. Anything I should watch out for? Is this guide fine: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-8/what-happened-to-backup-restore

Comment: undo the guide. Copy the folder back to C:\ and remvoe the link. I use LSE for link handling: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#download

Comment: @magicandre1981 I wanted to do that but I don't think quite understand how to do the commands in reverse...